# Linux - /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios file couldnt create

Tags: linux, fedora, nagios

I am trying to install nagios 4.0.6  and nagios -plugins-2.0.2 on fedora 17.
I have followed steps which is mentioned in sourceforge documentation.

http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/quickstart-fedora.html

unfortunately /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios this file isnt created I mean even bin folder haven't created. so that I am unable to start nagios service.
What should I do?

Comment: Did you run the installation step as root ?

Comment: Yes I did. but still facing same problem. Even I tried to find .. /bin/nagios using find command but no results found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install `Nagios` right from the Fedora repositories.

```
yum install nagios nagios-plugins
```

You can also see a list of `Nagios`-related packages with: `yum search nagios`.

I suggest you always install apps from the repositories, since the `package manager` will take care of the dependencies as well as the installation, and the packages there have been already revised and tested for the version of your OS. Use only 3rd party source builds or install/build the packages *manually* as a last resort.

Comment: Yeah thats true. I removed all previous packages and simply follow your query and its done . Thank you so much. :)